# WSO2 losing connection to RabbitMQ nodes

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We have WSO2 MI 4.1 using RabbitMQ to store/retrieve messages. We have a cluster of three RabbitMQ nodes and when we need to patch the OS of the hosting servers we bring down each node of RabbitMQ at a time.

When RabbitMQ node 1 goes down, WSO2 can still store messages. Once node 1 is patched and we bring down RabbitMQ node 2, WSO2 fails to store the messages.

WSO2 logs the below error:
*org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: connection is already closed due to connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)*

After node 2 is complete and fully available, WSO2 still can't write on RabbitMQ, then we proceed to patch node 3 and it's the same situation. Once node 3 is done and the three RabbitMQ nodes are available, we must restart the WSO2 services to have everything working again.

Initially, I posted this issue in the RabbitMQ community (in google groups) and they suggested that the issue may be that WSO2 was connected to RabbitMQ node 2 and when this node comes down, RabbitMQ is not able to try to connect to another available node.

Is our configuration to connect to RabbitMQ not correct?

Thanks

We have replicated this behavior in other two non-PROD environments

Comment: It seems not many users use RabbitMQ in their WSO2 implementations. I should start thinking about replacing RabbitMQ. Maybe I'll create another question asking for suggestions.